# CMake: How to build projects in a cross-platform manner?

Tags: cmake

I'm trying to build a project in a cross-platform manner.

I'm using CMake to generate project files on the fly, but it's not clear how to then compile those project files in a cross-platform way. I found `try_compile` but it's not clear whether this will do what I want. Any ideas?

For example, say I am using Visual Studio 2010 against project `foo`. I am expecting CMake to generate `foo.sln`, and then build it (generate the binaries). I know how to automate the first part, but how do I automate the second?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the [CMake docs](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/cmake-2-8-docs.html#section_Description):

> "CMake is a cross-platform build system generator."

So in other words, once CMake has generated the project files, it's work is really done.

You can invoke the native build tool via CMake using the `--build` flag, e.g.

```
cmake --build . --config Release --target install -- /M:4
```

See [here](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/cmake-2-8-docs.html#opt%3a--builddir) for further info.